# Given the inequalities $n > 2^k - 1$ and $n < 2^{(k+1)}$, express $k$ in terms of $n$ (where $k, n \in\Bbb N$).

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, logarithms, ceiling-and-floor-functions, natural-numbers

I am quite certain that it will require logarithms and the floor function.

I haven't really attempted this on my own, because I have no idea how to even approach this problem. I have, however, spent a good bit of time thinking about it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a fundamental mathematical problem of inequalities? (In my understanding)
I think we need to solve a set of inequalities representing the relationship between two natural numbers in expressions. In this problem, we need to express the natural number $k$ as an expression for another natural number $n$ that satisfies both inequalities given. This is a common mathematical problem that can be solved by algebraic operations and mathematical reasoning.

We are given the inequalities $n > 2^{k} - 1$ and $n < 2^{(k+1)}$, where $k$ and n are natural numbers. The problem asks us to express k in terms of n.

We can solve for k by manipulating the inequalities algebraically. First, let's rewrite $2^{(k+1)}$ as $2\times 2^k$:

\begin{aligned} n > 2^k - 1 \\ n < 2 \cdot 2^k \\ \end{aligned}

We can then solve for k by taking logarithms base 2:

\begin{aligned} k < \log_2(n+1) \\ k \geq \log_2 \frac{n}{2} \end{aligned}

Since k is a natural number, we can take the ceiling of the lower bound:

\begin{aligned} k = \left\lceil \log_2 \frac{n}{2} \right\rceil \end{aligned}

where $\lceil x \rceil$ denotes the smallest integer greater than or equal to $x$.

This expression for $k$ satisfies both inequalities, and is the simplest possible expression in terms of $n$.

Comment: Actually, the inequalities were n > (2^k) - 1 and n < 2^(k+1). Sorry for the misunderstanding, I am new to MathJax. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Then I edited my original answer. Using the log trick to avoid the order.

Comment: Thanks! Just one question, why take the ceiling of the lower bound instead of the floor of the upper bound.

Comment: we can take the ceiling of the lower bound because we know that k must be a natural number. The lower bound gives us the smallest possible value of k that satisfies the second inequality, while the upper bound gives us the largest possible value of k that satisfies the first inequality. However, the upper bound may not necessarily be a natural number.

For example, consider the inequality $n > 2^{k - 1}$. If $n = 7$, then the upper bound on $k$ is $k < log_2(7+1) = 3.81$. However, k cannot be 3.81 because $k$ must be a natural number. Therefore, we must take the ceiling of the lower bound

Comment: On the other hand, if the upper bound on k is a natural number, then we could take the floor of the upper bound instead of the ceiling of the lower bound. For example, if the second inequality was $n < 2^{(k+2)}$ instead of $n < 2^{(k+1)}$, then the upper bound on k would be a natural number $(k < log_2(n/4))$. In that case, we could take the floor of the upper bound to get the largest natural number k that satisfies both inequalities.